# if you hadn't done this, it would be... or it would have been

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-perfect

Which one is correct?

> If you hadn't done this, it would be this.

or

> If you hadn't done this, it would have been that.

I am having trouble with understanding this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd example is correct.

Your sentence: it would be this” is referring to a hypothetical situation in the future.

> If I were a doctor, I would treat you

“If were a doctor” present. “I would treat you” future. So, I admit your 2nd example is all fine. Your first example would have been correct too, had you written it as “If you didn’t do this, it would be that way.